# Does leaving the GPU attached damage it if I never use it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, pci-express, hardware-rec

I've built my own server PC which has been up and running for about 2 weeks now.

Since the initial setting-up of the OS, it has not been plugged into a monitor - I instead just access it via SSH from my laptop, because it's simpler and more convenient.

The only things plugged directly into the server are the ethernet cable, and the power cable.

---

So now, the server no longer needs its graphics card (an Asus GeForce GT 710) which has just been sitting in its PCIe slot unused for the past 2 weeks.

**My question is this:**

Is it fine to just leave the GPU in the PCIe slot even if I never use it? Does it cause any damage to the component, or is it harmless and there's no need to pack it up and store it?

Comment: The system will most likely not boot without a graphics solution. So you don't really have a choice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its fine to leave the card, unused in the system, and it won't cause any damage.

If you do want to pack it up and store it, it might save a tiny bit of power and make configuring the system a tiny bit more straight forward - but be sure to take static management precautions.